# Safety of writing fund transfer and NFT transfer code in an externally linked library

Tags: nft, library, reentrant-attacks, eth-call

If suppose there is a main contract A that is linked to an external library L, would it be safe to move all the fund transfer and NFT transfer calls from the main contract into the library to reduce the size of contract A. The **sendFundsAndToken** function is made nonReentrant.

contract without using a library:

```
contract A{
 function sendFundsAndToken(address collectionAddress, uint256 tokenId) external nonReentrant{
  payable(msg.sender).call{ value: 1 ether }("");
  ERC721(collectionAddress).safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
 }
}
```

contract using a library:

```
contract A{
 function sendFundsAndToken(address collectionAddress, uint256 tokenId) external nonReentrant{
  L.executeSend(collectionAddress, tokenId);
 }
}

library L{
 function executeSend(address collectionAddress, uint256 tokenId) external{
  payable(msg.sender).call{ value: 1 ether }("");
  ERC721(collectionAddress).safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
 }
}
```